# How to use Guava Cache with secondary index key?

Tags: java, database, caching, relational-database, guava

Whenever we look to retrieve data from multiple keys, we choose to lean over databases. I have a Class Cart as shown:

```
@Data
public class Cart {

    private String cartId;

    private String restaurantId;

    private String userId;

    @NotNull
    private String deviceId;

    private Map<String, Integer> items;
}
```

I want to retrieve my cart with userId or deviceId. In a RDBMS, the way would have been declaring deviceId(primary key) and userId(unique key) which would have been sufficient for me to retrieve the cart efficiently with either of these.

Is there a clean way to achieve this with Guava or some other cache? By clean, I expect it to be first class construct provided in the cache so that I don't have to write a wrapper around it to use.

Comment: A lot more detail would be useful in answering this question.  What do you mean "retrieve data from multiple keys"?  Do you have multiple keys and are trying to look up the value for their combination?  Are you trying to support multiple kinds of keys at once?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this with Guava is to have two caches, one to look up by deviceId and one to look up by userId.

I don't know if you consider that clean enough, but I'd consider that the best possible type-safe solution.

Comment: An [ancient](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/wiki/IndexableCache.md) bit of code (and probably ugly nowadays; could be 10x smaller) that I wrote trying to do this was to use a cache with secondary key extractors to build the index. It used lock striping when update the two maps. We later took the better ideas explored by this project (striped, bloom filter, size caching) and discarded the rest as too exploratory and special case.

Comment: @LouisWasserman this will work as I will have to write a wrapper to make sure write happens at both the caches. Was curious if this is not a generic problem? I was surprised to not find any cache implementing as first class construct, but application has to do this.

Comment: @BenManes thanks for sharing this super relevant and useful resource. I think it may help me solve.